# Loading A Spinner from a Button

Tags: javascript, html, spinner

I'm trying to load a spinner as soon as a button is hit. I'm using Spinkit library. The aim is to display the spinner for about 3 seconds AFTER the button is clicked, just before the page loads. But it doesn't take a second before the spinner shows. Please take a look:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="spinkit.min.css">
    <style>
        .example  {
            margin: 50px 100px;
            padding: 100px; 
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            display: none; 
                    }
         .sk-plane {
              height: 50px;
              background-color: darkviolet;
      }
    </style> 
    <script>


     function spp(){

         let spi = setInterval(spiny, 3000);
     };    
        spp();

      function spiny(){

         let showie = document.querySelector('.example');
          showie.style.display = 'block';

          };
        </script>

    </head>
<body>

    <button class='tay' onclick='spiny()'>
        <a href="#" > Press Here </a>          
      </button>



        <center class="example">
            <button class="sk-plane"> </button>
           </center>




</body>
</html>
```

Here is the [source](https://github.com/tobiasahlin/SpinKit/blob/master/README.md) of the Spinkit file

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval(func|code, [delay])` will run your code once the delay has come to an end **including the first time**.
To solve your problem i would suggest to fire your spinner function when you button is clicked and by using `setTimeout(func|code, [delay])` stop it after X amount of time. `setTimeout` takes the same parameters as `setInterval` but it runs the function/code once when the delay has ended. you can find more info [here](https://javascript.info/settimeout-setinterval).

Answer (score 0):

if .example is the class of the spinner container you just need to show this when the user clicks on the button and hide it after 3 seconds:

```
function spiny(){
    let spinner = document.querySelector('.example');
    spinner.style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(() => {
        spinner.style.display = 'none';
    }, 3000);
}
```